# in phantomjs,how to pass variables from page context to outside the page context

Tags: phantomjs

consider the following snippet.how can i access the value of the page url outside the page context?globally accessing the value was not working either.callbacks wasn't clear to me in approach.

```
page.onUrlChanged = function(targetUrl) {
console.log('New URL: ' + targetUrl);
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
console.log(msg);
};
var abc=page.open(url,function(status){
page.evaluate(function(){
//some code;
})
return page.url; 
});
console.log(abc);
```

the code always gives undefined page url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS documents are very much recommended: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

```
page.open(url,function(status){
    var current_url = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.location.href; 
    })

    console.log(current_url);
});
```

Comment: let's say we use the statement url="hello" instead of the console.log(url) statement,how can we access this new value "hello" of the url outside page.open?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, please rephrase or provide another example (maybe in a new question)